# Page did not shows the updated data.

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, redirect

Experts,
I have a website in that my page load event is not called, when  I have clicked on the button it's page load call. 
I know there is some small issue,but I can't find out the reason.  There may be any from server side to cache the page? I am using the update panel on the pages.

below is the URL.

https://www.primaryresearch.com/

Check out any 2 products (1 by 1) , in the cart only one product will show.

when you access the url https://www.primaryresearch.com/shoppingcart.aspx after add the product in cart. (just copy and paste in browser after add the product in cart), I will show the correct data. both page have the same code.

Please help me to find out the reason of this.

Comment: Adding item in cart shows error page. It redirects to https://www.primaryresearch.com/ViewCart.aspx with parse error. And without seeing your code we can not determine what is the issue.

Comment: This is the main reason , website seems to be cache and did not update the content, It is not showing any error my side. I did not use any caching.